# Moving to new webhost keep email at old webhost

Tags: domain-name-system, web-hosting, mediatemple

I'm moving to a new web host and would like to keep my exchange email at the old web host.

I just want my website at the new web host.

Can I just tell my old web host to change the A record for www.domain.com to point to the IP address of my new server? Or does it need to point to the nameserver of my new server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can have the old host change the A record to your new web servers IP address.  Or you might be able to change the DNS records yourself via there control panel if they offer that.  Remember DNS changes can take up to 48 hours in some cases depending on the TTL.  Normally just a few hours after clearing DNS caches.

Comment: thanks. I had the old host change the A records for www.domain.com and domain.com to point to the IP address of my new server. Pinging the domain shows that it now resolves to my new server. Pulling it up in a browser just doesn't work yet. Is that because of propagation?

Comment: Clear the cache in your browser should resolve the issue.

Comment: it just doesn't seem to make sense. I can ping the domain and it shows it is talking to my new server. but when i try to access it in a browser it doesnt work. maybe i need to setup something different at mediatemple.

Comment: also it appears they only setup the A record to www.domain.com and forgot to setup a record to just domain.com. that may be the culprit. is there anyway i can edit my zone file to account for this?

Answer (score 0):

You should have your domains registered someplace else like Godaddy. Then you can config and change it yourself. You can point the port 80 to web hosting company and the email somewhere else. 
If your hosting service goes down (like a 9.1 quake) you can switch quickly.